# numpy array using more loops than it should. why?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, timeit

```
%timeit [i **2  for i in range(1000)]
print('*******')
%timeit np.arange(1000) ** 2
```

prints:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 376 µs per loop
*******
The slowest run took 11.43 times longer than the fastest. This could 
mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.76 µs per loop
```

My intuition is numpy should iterate through the whole array once and square each element. Then why does timeit say numpy code loops 100000 times.

Comment: You haven't read what the `timeit` module does. Read the docs! "loop" doesn't refer to what the code you test does, but how often that code is executed.

Comment: That loop count is the number of times the timer is executed. For a code that takes lesser time, the timer is run more number of times. Your second code is faster, hence timer decides it to run for more number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. But `%timeit` executes your command in a loop N times to get a good statistical estimate.

You can specify the number of loops using the `n` option like:

```
%timeit -n1 arange(1, 100, .001)    # one loop
%timeit -n10 arange(1, 100, .001).  # ten loops
```

See also the [documentation of `%timeit`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit).

Comment: The doc says Options: -n<N>: execute the given statement <N> times in a loop. If this value is not given, a fitting value is chosen. Any idea on how a fitting value is chosen?

Comment: @claudius It's chosen such that the total time is >= 0.2 sec. Source code - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/timeit.py#L210-216